# Can python extract org-mode tables from org documents?

Tags: python, csv, org-mode

I'm trying to write some python code that reads specified tables in [org mode](http://orgmode.org/) documents. For example, I have a file `~/foo.org`

```
$ cat ~/foo.org
#+Title: Example Org Document

* Section One

Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus.

#+TBLNAME: table1
| i     | want    | python | to     |
|-------+---------+--------+--------|
| read  | this    | table  | only   |
| 1     | 3       | 2      | 4      |
|-------+---------+--------+--------|
| i     | want    | the    | dashed |
| lines | ignored | by     | python |

#+TBLNAME: table2
|    i | don't |  need | python | to |
|------+-------+-------+--------+----|
| read |  this | table |      9 |  8 |
|    7 |     6 |     5 |      4 |  3 |
|    2 |     1 |     0 |     22 | 17 |
```

If my file were less complex, say

```
$ cat ~/bar.org
| i     | want    | python | to     |
| read  | this    | table  | only   |
| 1     | 3       | 2      | 4      |
| i     | want    | the    | dashed |
| lines | ignored | by     | python |
```

then I could read the table into python with

```
import csv
csv.DictReader(open('~/bar.org'), delimiter='|')
```

Is there any way to parse my desired table from the more complicated `~/foo.org`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do if you control the input format you expect is to read the entire file into python, extract with a regular expression the table of interest, then pass this to csv:

```
import csv, re
data = open("foo.org").read()
mo = re.search("TBLNAME: table1\n.*?\n(\n|$)", data, re.S)
mytable = mo.group(0)
d = csv.DictReader(mytable.splitlines(), delimiter='|')
```

You need to convert the string `mytable` into an iterable for the csv reader, eg as shown here by splitting out the lines.

Comment: Any idea how to change `*?\n\n` so that it respects tables appearing at the end of the file (without spaces below)?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick You can replace the 2nd `\n` by the pattern `(\n|$)`. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Python function that reads and adds the lines whose first and last character is a '|' to a table (which could be a list object where each item is one line of the table).

If you have several tables, a line not beginning with '|' is the hint for 'end-of-table'.